# C# - Build task - TFS Services Replace Tokens build step does not replace password protected values in App.config file

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, msbuild

I am creating a Selenium build where I am passing all the values to App.config from outside using Replace Tokens. When I specify the variables as a non - password protected field, the values App.config file gets replaced. But once the values are password protected ( see image attachment ) from the variables tab, replace tokens build step is not replacing the replacing the values with the parameterized values.

[image]

Comment: What did you find in the build log? Could your share related info of the log?

Comment: Which version of the task are you using? I just tried with the latest 1.3.0 version but didn't see any issue. It can replace the strings correctly with the secret variable.

Comment: I used the one which came in the build step list. Must be the latest.

Comment: The logs says  -->       `Set workingFolder to default: C:\BuildAgent\tasks\ReplaceTokens\0.0.16
Starting regex replacement in [C:/BuildAgent/_work/3/s/XXXX/App.config]
Token [password] does not have an environment value
Token [screenshotlocation] does not have an environment value`

Comment: The build is successful but the password is `_password_` and the screenshotlocation is `_screenshotlocation_`

Comment: These are the original values supplied in the app.confg file which I expected to replace

Comment: "Replace Token" task is an extension which isn't included in TFS out of box features. Can you check the version of it on "Manage Extensions" page?